# Can I use R to trim a video, like I do with ffmpeg?

Tags: r, video, ffmpeg, trim, cut

I have several video files that I need to trim/cut (i.e., cut 00:05:00 - 00:10:00 among 2-hour-long video). I can trim/cut each video by using ffmpeg. However, since I have +100 video files that need to be trimmed, I would like to use R loop function to do it.

I've found that there are several R packages that people use for video processing, such as imager or magick, but I cannot find a way to trim a video using R.

Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have to do this through R? Why not just a batch file/shell script/for loop in the terminal? That said, I do sometimes use R to construct the command I want to use in ffmpeg and use `system()` to execute it. What OS are you using?

Comment: I am doing this via R only because I have only used R before. I am new to coding. I am using windows 10. Thank you so much for your coment. I wil try to figure out how to use system( ) and/or batch file/shell script/for loop in the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic approach to trimming a video with `ffmpeg` would be something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:05:00 -to 00:10:00 -c copy output.mp4
```

To create a batch file, you can put the following in a text file and save it as something like "trimvideo.bat" and run it in the relevant folder.

```sh
@echo off
:: loops across all the mp4s in the folder
for %%A in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -i "%%A"^
  :: the commands you would use for processing one file
  -ss 00:05:00 -to 00:10:00 -c copy ^
  :: the new file (original_trimmed.mp4)
  "%%~nA_trimmed.mp4"
pause
```

If you wanted to do this through R, you could do something like:

```
# get a list of the files you're working with
x <- list.files(pattern = "*.mp4")

for (i in seq_along(x)) {
  cmd <- sprintf("ffmpeg -i %s -ss 00:05:00 -to 00:10:00 -c copy %_trimmed.mp4",
                 x[i], sub(".mp4$", "", x[i]))
  system(cmd)
}
```

I've used a similar approach in the past when I've wanted to cut specific parts from a file or multiple files. In those cases, I start with a `data.frame` similar to the following:

```
df <- data.frame(file = c("file_A.mp4", "file_B.mp4", "file_A.mp4"),
                 start = c("00:01:00", "00:05:00", "00:02:30"),
                 end = c("00:02:20", "00:07:00", "00:04:00"),
                 output = c("segment_1.mp4", "segment_2.mp4", "segment_3.mp4"))
df
#         file    start      end        output
# 1 file_A.mp4 00:01:00 00:02:20 segment_1.mp4
# 2 file_B.mp4 00:05:00 00:07:00 segment_2.mp4
# 3 file_A.mp4 00:02:30 00:04:00 segment_3.mp4
```

I use `sprintf` to create the `ffmpeg` commands I want to run:

```
cmds <- with(df, sprintf("ffmpeg -i %s -ss %s -to %s -c copy %s", 
                         file, start, end, output)) 
cmds
# [1] "ffmpeg -i file_A.mp4 -ss 00:01:00 -to 00:02:20 -c copy segment_1.mp4"
# [2] "ffmpeg -i file_B.mp4 -ss 00:05:00 -to 00:07:00 -c copy segment_2.mp4"
# [3] "ffmpeg -i file_A.mp4 -ss 00:02:30 -to 00:04:00 -c copy segment_3.mp4"
```

And I run it using `lapply(..., system)`:

```
lapply(cmds, system)
```

You can also look at the `av` package, but I've always just preferred using a loop at the terminal or creating the commands to be run using `sprintf` and using `system()`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your super kind help. You are an angel :) Your codes seem definitely doable and make sense. Have a happy day!

Comment: @TaeJinHwang, Glad to help, and good luck! You may need to make sure that `ffmpeg` is in your path and visible to R. You should be able to do `Sys.which("ffmpeg")` to see if R can find `ffmpeg`. Otherwise, you can change your `sprintf` command to specify the absolute path of the `ffmpeg` binary.

Comment: I've found in the data.frame approach (in linux, though likely applicable to win and OSx) that a further `df$filter <- paste0('"', df$filter, '"')`prior to creation of `cmds`, that is saying 'supply this to 'with(some_df, sprintf(the quoted things here'  call within double quotes rather than assuming the `df$my_filter` displayed value that appears quoted, in r, is not otherwise properly interpreted by `system` as a quoted string. With this addition, the above approach has been excellent.