# Converting ffmpeg loudnorm first pass dcf summary report output to data.frame R

Tags: r, ffmpeg

Following from [operations on a video with ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62804755/can-i-use-r-to-trim-a-video-like-i-do-with-ffmpeg), a `loudnorm` first pass report for purely audio files is produced

```
names(aud_proc_df)
[1] "in_files" "proc_out" "filter"

cmds_loudness_report <- with(aud_proc_df, sprintf("ffmpeg -hide_banner -i %s -af loudnorm=I=-23:TP=-2:LRA=7:print_format=summary -f null /dev/null 2>&1 | tail -n 12 >> loudness_rpt_all.txt", in_files)) # linux specific notation
lapply(cmds_loudness_report, system)
```

reading this as a .csv rather than .dcf

```
loudness_df_csv <- read.csv('loudness_rpt_all.txt', header = FALSE, sep =':')
head(loudness_df_csv)
                 V1                  V2
1  Input Integrated          -24.7 LUFS
2   Input True Peak           -1.6 dBTP
3         Input LRA             17.9 LU
4   Input Threshold          -37.8 LUFS
5 Output Integrated          -23.4 LUFS
6  Output True Peak           -2.0 dBTP
#data
structure(list(V1 = c("Input Integrated", "Input True Peak", 
"Input LRA", "Input Threshold", "Output Integrated", "Output True Peak", 
"Output LRA", "Output Threshold", "Normalization Type", "Target Offset", 
"Input Integrated", "Input True Peak", "Input LRA", "Input Threshold", 
"Output Integrated", "Output True Peak", "Output LRA", "Output Threshold", 
"Normalization Type", "Target Offset"), V2 = c("    -24.7 LUFS", 
"      -1.6 dBTP", "            17.9 LU", "     -37.8 LUFS", 
"   -23.4 LUFS", "     -2.0 dBTP", "           14.8 LU", "    -36.2 LUFS", 
"   Dynamic", "        +0.4 LU", "    -23.9 LUFS", "      +0.2 dBTP", 
"            22.0 LU", "     -37.6 LUFS", "   -23.6 LUFS", "     -2.0 dBTP", 
"           21.9 LU", "    -37.0 LUFS", "   Dynamic", "        +0.6 LU"
)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

then, for column notation portability between win and linux systems

```
df_names <- unique(loudness_df_csv$V1)
df_names2 <- gsub(' ', '_', df_names)
```

and then make a data.frame

```
loudnorm_rpt <- data.frame(loudness_df_csv$V2[which(loudness_df_csv$V1 == df_names[1])], loudness_df_csv$V2[which(loudness_df_csv$V1 == df_names[2])], loudness_df_csv$V2[which(loudness_df_csv$V1 == df_names[3])], loudness_df_csv$V2[which(loudness_df_csv$V1 == df_names[4])], loudness_df_csv$V2[which(loudness_df_csv$V1 == df_names[5])], loudness_df_csv$V2[which(loudness_df_csv$V1 == df_names[6])], loudness_df_csv$V2[which(loudness_df_csv$V1 == df_names[7])], loudness_df_csv$V2[which(loudness_df_csv$V1 == df_names[8])], loudness_df_csv$V2[which(loudness_df_csv$V1 == df_names[9])], loudness_df_csv$V2[which(loudness_df_csv$V1 == df_names[10])])
names(loudnorm_rpt) <- df_names2
rownames(loudnorm_rpt) <- c('A', 'B')
```

Should I just wrap this in a function or is there a dcf to data.frame function that I've missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a `matrix` out of `V2` and use `make.names`.

```
f <- \(x) {
  x <- x[order(x$V1), ]
  `dimnames<-`(matrix(trimws(x$V2), 2), 
               list(c('A', 'B'), make.names(unique(x$V1)))) |>
    as.data.frame()
}

f(loudness_df_csv)
#   Input.Integrated Input.LRA Input.Threshold Input.True.Peak
# A       -24.7 LUFS   17.9 LU      -37.8 LUFS       -1.6 dBTP
# B       -23.9 LUFS   22.0 LU      -37.6 LUFS       +0.2 dBTP
#   Normalization.Type Output.Integrated Output.LRA Output.Threshold
# A            Dynamic        -23.4 LUFS    14.8 LU       -36.2 LUFS
# B            Dynamic        -23.6 LUFS    21.9 LU       -37.0 LUFS
#   Output.True.Peak Target.Offset
# A        -2.0 dBTP       +0.4 LU
# B        -2.0 dBTP       +0.6 LU
```

More general:

```
g <- \(x) {
  x <- x[order(x[, 1]), ]
  l <- tapply(x[, 1], x[, 1], length)[[1]]
  `dimnames<-`(matrix(trimws(x[, 2]), l), 
               list(NULL, make.names(unique(x$V1)))) |>
    as.data.frame()
}
```

Comment: To generalize to 'any number of recordings', adjusted to f <- \(x, recordings) {, matrix(..., length(recordings)), list(recordings, ...  Very handy.

Comment: @Chris Added an updated version that calculates number of records automatically.

Comment: I'm probably a bonehead, but above I used `rownames(` to decorate final result df with actual, very long file names that were not included in `x`, calling them A,B for MRE. How, in the above `g` would NULL be populated, or is it a placeholder? And congrats on 54K.

Comment: @Chris They are included in the `\`dimnames<-\`()` function call, provided as a list of rownames (that I set to `NULL` which will yield ordinary numbers, since the alphabet might be insufficient if records exceed 26), and colnames; we could it see as generalization of the two subfunctions `rownames` and `colnames`. Note that they actually refer to matrices, and the equivalent for data frames would be `row.names` and `names`, but the former also works for the latter. Thx for congrats.